# Expected value and variance on exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The length of time Y necessary to complete a key operation in the construction of houses has an exponential distribution with mean 10 hours. The formula C = 100 + 40Y + 3Y^2 relate the cost C of completing this operation to the square of the time to completion. Find the mean and variance of C. 
For E(C), I found 1100 
For V(C), I found V(100+40Y+3Y^2) = V(100) + V(40Y)+ V(3Y^2)
= 1600V(Y) + 9V(Y^2). However, I do not know how to evaluate 9V(Y^2)?

Could anyone check my answer and help me out to evaluate 9V(Y^2)?

Comment: This is wrong. You can only use $V(X+Y) = V(X) + V(Y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated.  That's not the case for $40 Y$ and $3 Y^2$.  A more general formula is $V(X+Y) = V(X) + V(Y) + 2 Cov(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density function of $Y$ is $\lambda e^{-\lambda y}$ (for $y\gt 0$).

Your answer for $E(C)$ is correct. The proposed procedure for calculating the variance of $C$ is not correct. The formula for the variance of a linear combination of **independent** random variables was used. But $40Y$ and $3Y^2$ are not independent.

We can simplify the calculation a little by discarding the constant $100$. That does not change the variance. So we want
$$E((40Y+3Y^2)^2 -(E(40Y+3Y^2))^2.$$
To calculate the first term, we need
$$\int_0^\infty (40y+3y^2)^2 \lambda e^{-\lambda y}\,dy.$$
Expand. We can save some integrations by looking up or computing the mgf of our exponential.

Comment: Is there any easier way to compute the first term?

Comment: I don't think so. It is not too bad, particularly if we use the moment generating function. Or use the fact that with transformation $u=y/10$ we are evaluating $\Gamma$ functions.

Comment: V(C) = 1000000?

Comment: That's the square of the mean of $40Y+9Y^2$, which is the term you subtract from the first harder term. My calculations are not reliable, but I get variance $2920000$.

Comment: Do you mind you show your calculation ?

Comment: Briefly, we want the expectation of (i) $1600Y^2+240Y^3+9Y^4$, from which we will subtract the square of the expectation of $40Y+3Y^2$. By your calculation, the expectation of $40Y+3Y^2$ is $1000$. For (i) we get $(1600)(2!)(100)+(240)(3!)(1000)+(9)(4!)(10000)$. I used the moment generating function of the exponential.

Comment: What formula does you use for Calculating E(Y^3) and E(Y^4)?

Comment: Instead of integrating, as in $\int \frac{y^3}{10}r^{-y/10}\,dy$, which can be done by parts but is a nuisance, I used the moment generating function of the exponential. Look at Wikipedia, exponential distribution. Alternately, you can let $u=-y/10$ and look up the definition of the Gamma function.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The $k$'th moment of an exponential random variable with mean $\mu$ is
$E[Y^k] = k! \mu^k$ for nonnegative integer $k$.